# How to change the size of points in the geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I am new to blender. Currently, I am trying to make a donut and I am stuck with making the sprinkles. My points[image] in geometry nodes are too big, how do I change the size of them?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "set point radius" node for that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In complement to Chris answer, you'll need to use this radius, when instancing, if you want to change instance size(s):

[image]